# Send context the template in a class based view

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

How can I send context to my template in a class-based view with the `get_object` function?

This is my class:

```
class DetailMessages(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView, ChannelFormMixin):
    template_name = 'DM/chat.html'
    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        my_username = self.request.user.username
        username = self.kwargs.get("username")
        channel, _ = Channel.objects.get_dm_channel(my_username, username)
        if channel == None:
            raise Http404
        context = {"example1" : "I want this on the template", "example2" : "I want this on the template too"}
        return channel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually not good idea to mix methods in class based views. You can pass context in two ways: in `get()` or `get_context_data()`. Examples:

```
# or

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context["example1"] = "I want this on the template"
    context["example2"] = "I want this on the template too"
    return context

# or

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {}
    context["example1"] = "I want this on the template"
    context["example2"] = "I want this on the template too"
    return render(..., context=context)
```

If you don't actually need to operate with `get()` (or `post()`) method, then much better way is to leave context managing to `get_context_data()` method.